# Short story about a boy who brings a roach back to life

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, powers

I'm trying to find information about a short story which involved a little boy who brings a dead cockroach back to life at the end of the story. I recall that he is repeatedly told to stop playing with it by adults who think he's just playing with a gross squashed bug before it is revealed what he's done, and that there was at least a hint of physical abuse by his father, but I might be getting those details mixed up with something else.

The short story was part of a paperback book collection of genre fiction that I borrowed from a friend and read at least 30 years ago, probably around 1991, and I recall the book looked pretty weathered, so possibly published much earlier than that. It was definitely not meant to be read by children, if that helps.

Comment: Reminds me of Christopher Moore's *Lamb* but that's not a short story, and the only critters brought back to life (as far as I can recall) are lizards. And the boy is the young Jesus Christ, which you probably would have remembered and put in your description.

Comment: This may be a false memory, but I'm sure I remember a story like this that ends with something like _He opened his fist and the cockroach scuttled away_. If I'm right maybe this will help jog memories.

Comment: @JohnRennie that does actually sound familiar, like I kind of remember that the reveal that he has brought the cockroach back to life was how the story ends. That does help!

Comment: @user14111, don't remember him being Jesus and it was definitely a short story, but there may have been some allusion to him being the second coming of Jesus for all I know. But it was set in more modern times, probably the "present."

Answer (score 10):

This bears some resemblance to *[Talent](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45091)* by Theodore Sturgeon, which has been widely anthologized, including in [*Fifty Short Science Fiction Tales*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?294289) and available [here](https://archive.org/details/Beyond_Fantasy_Fiction_v01n02_1953-09_cape1736/page/n57/mode/2up).

In the story, a young (seven-ish) boy named Joachim (or "Jokey") is playing with another child, a girl nicknamed "Precious." Jokey has reality-warping powers (like Anthony from "It's A Good Life," but without the telepathy). In the story he does thoughtlessly cruel things, like turn a pig into a living piggy bank. Near the end of the story, he turns himself into a very large beetle to frighten the girl, and this happens:

> Something moved into her field of vision. She glanced at it, squealed,
> and moved back. It was an enormous stag beetle, three times life-size,
> and it was scuttling toward her.
>
> Another beetle— or the same one— met her at the corner.
>
> With her hard black shiny shoes, she stepped on this one, so hard that
> the calf of her leg ached and tingled for the next half-hour.

Resulting in this:

> In the car, Mrs. Brent told her husband that she thought Jokey was
> driving Mrs. Purney crazy.
>
> It was her turn to be driven very nearly mad, the next morning, when
> Jokey turned up. Most of him.
>
> Surprising, really, how much beetle had stuck to the hard black shoe,
> and, when it was time, turned into what they found under their
> daughter’s bed.

**Implications of abuse:**

> “What about your father?” “Aw, I guess he’d like to lick me. But he
> ain’t got a* chance. Mom’d have a fit.”
>
> “You mean she’d get mad at him?”
>
> “No, stoopid. A fit. You know, scrabbles at the air and get suds on
> her mouth, and all. Falls down and twitches.” He chuckled. “But-why?”
>
> “Well, it’s about the on’y way she can handle Pop, I guess. He’s
> always wanting to do something about me. She won’t let ’um, so I c’n
> do anything I want.”

and

> “He’s got to be given everything he wants,” murmured Mrs. Purney in a
> strange tone. It was fierce and it was by rote. “He’s got to be kept
> happy.”
>
> “You must love him very much,” snapped Mrs. Brent viciously, suddenly
> determined to get some reaction out of this weak, indulgent creature.
> She got it.
>
> “I hate him,” said Mrs. Purney.
>
> Her eyes were closed again, and now she. almost smiled, as if the
> release of those words had been a yearned-for thing. Then she sat
> abruptly erect, her pale eyes round, and she grasped her lower lip and
> pulled it absurdly down and to the side.
>
> “I didn’t mean that,” she gasped. She flung herself down before Mrs.
> Brent, and gabbled, “I didn’t mean it! Don’t tell him! He’ll do things
> to us. He’ll loosen the housebeams when we’re sleeping. He’ll turn the
> breakfast to snakes and frogs, and make that big toothy mouth again
> out of the oven door. Don’t tell him! Don’t tell him!” Mrs. Brent,
> profoundly shocked, and not comprehending a word of this,
> instinctively put out her arms and gathered the other woman close.

Comment: Thank you for responding with so much detail! I just read the story you linked to and, although I do see why you suggested it, I am pretty sure it's not the one I'm referring to. I did get a kick out of it and the similarities to the classic Twilight Zone episode though! I also appreciated the links provided; now I can go down a new rabbit hole I wasn't familiar with to try and find what I'm looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem.Hope you find the story you're looking for